# Drop down menu not working properly

Tags: html, css

I created a drop-down menu using HTML and CSS.

It works fine but the sub-menus displays even when the mouse is hovered upon them when they are not visible. I just want the sub-menus to be displayed when mouse is hovered on the main menu item. I am using `opacity` and `z-index` features. I don't want to use `display: none` to hide the sub-menus as I want to use transition effects.

```css
#nav > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 40px;
  list-style: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 4px;
}
#nav > ul > li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  top: 50px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -999;
  transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}
#nav > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Linpaws</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Swapnil 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Swapnil 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Swapnil 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

</div>
```

Please suggest what I should do to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `visibility: hidden;` and `opacity: 0;` to hide the sub menu. Example:

```css
ul, li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  margin-top: 0;
}
ul > li > a {
  display: block;
}
ul > li > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
ul > li > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}
ul > li > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #0072bc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href='#'>Main</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Submenu 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Submenu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Submenu 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your answer could be more specific to the OP's question. You could have just said the OP needed  to add `visibility: hidden;` to `#nav > ul > li > ul` and  `visibility: visible;` to `#nav > ul > li:hover > ul`.

Comment: Nanang Mahdaen El-Agun, @IMI "visibility" feature worked perfectly. Thanks to both of you...!!

Answer (score 1):

Close your first `<ul>` tag to get it to work.

---

**Edit**
Your problem is that, as long as the mouse hovers over `#nav > ul > li`, the sub-menu is displayed, but the sub-menu itself is part of this very `li`. Instead you could tie the `:hover` selector to the main menu `a`, and then apply the `opacity:1` to the next sibling, like so:

```
#nav > ul > li > a:hover + ul {
    opacity:1;
    z-index:100;
    top:60px;
}
```

Maybe **[read up about the adjacent sibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)** if you don't know it yet.

Note that applying the `:hover` selector to the hyperlink `a` will result in the sub-menu only opening when the mouse is above the actual text and not necessarily the orange box that is around it. You can fix that by applying `display:block` to the hyperlink `a` and moving the `li` specific properties to the `li` styling, as follows:

```
#nav > ul > li {
    position:relative;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav > ul > li > a {
    display:block;
    font-size:40px;
    width:160px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:orange;
    padding:4px;
}
```

Comment: While it is a problem that should be fixed, this won't solve the issue the OP is having. https://jsfiddle.net/vc9jdwhp/

Comment: I see. Before I posted my answer I had tested it locally and it looked like the problem had been solved, but now that I test it again the problem is back. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you only want to show submenus, when main menu item is hovered ... it seems very odd, but ok ... here is a way to do it:

```
#nav > ul > li {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 40px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 4px;
}

#nav > ul > li:hover > ul { /* <<< moved from below */
    opacity: 1;             /* <<< moved from below */
    z-index: 100;           /* <<< moved from below */
    top: 60px;              /* <<< moved from below */
}                           /* <<< moved from below */

#nav > ul > li > ul, #nav > ul > li > ul:hover { /* <<< selector added */
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    top: 50px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -999;
    transition: 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

... And yea ... what Waflix said ... close your ul-tag :)